# Can you reactivate a previously expired data plan when travelling to Australia?

Tags: australia, cellphones, data-plans

My wife has previously held an Aussie phone number with Amaysim.  Can she reactivate that number but with a different provider, with different data plan etc, or does she have to go with Amaysim to re-activate it?

Comment: Can she re-activate the number at all or is it already handed out to someone else?

Comment: Doesn't appear handed out to anyone else

Answer (score 14):

Firstly, you need to determine whether your wife still owns that phone number.  The [Amaysim terms and conditions](https://www.amaysim.com.au/content/dam/amaysim/documents/terms-conditions/amaysim-General-Terms.pdf) suggest that a pre-paid service (and the phone number) is cancelled once it is inactive for 90 days.

Secondly, in order to port a number to another provider you will need to be able to verify your ownership of that number by receiving an SMS verification code or a telephone call.  This means you will need to reactivate with Amaysim before you can switch providers.  This [verification process](https://www.acma.gov.au/port-customers-phone-number#port-a-mobile-phone-number) was introduced recently.

Comment: Depending on the plan the SIM was previously used on, it may remain active for up to ~15 months since last used.  In general, Australian phones can still receive SMS messages (as required to port out) even when they have no credit on them, although not once they are actually cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-activate a phone number, also a dataplan only, as long as the phone number is still alive and as such still available to you.

It will partly depend on the phone company, some will be more generous with the time they allow the number to be retained by the last holder of it, others will retire the number very soon after the last credit ran out or the last credit upload is a given time period ago, regardless of leftover value.

So it seems rather likely that your wifes telephone number is no longer available to her, but it may be worth it to contact the company and see if she can still use it, or even get it again if not handed out to an other yet.